# How to use openapi.yaml file to generate swagger-ui?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have defined the REST API using an OpenApi specification file. Then I generated Java classes from this specification.
Is there a way to use api.yaml to generate swagger-ui.html instead of java classess?

I tried to create an endpoint (with /v3/api-docs path) that reads the file and returns the content of it as a http response. It's working but I have a feeling that there may be a better solution.

Commonly Swagger generates automatically `openapi.yaml` under the /v3/api-docs endpoint and the Swagerr UI uses it to generate swagger-ui.html. In my case I already have `openapi.yaml` but I don't know how to tell to Swagger-UI to take my file to generate the html page

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`openapi-generator`](https://openapi-generator.tech/) has several different generators which can read in a yaml file and output code in your preferred language.  Some of the generators include [`java`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/java.md), [`html`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/html.md), [`html2`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/html2.md), [`spring`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md), and [`javascript`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/javascript.md).  The comprehensive list of generators can be found [here](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators).

The `openapi-generator` can be ran via [CLI](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/installation), as well as its [maven and gradle plugins](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/plugins).

Since you already have a valid openapi specification file, I'd recommend using the generator to generate a spring server using the `spring-boot` library and set the [`documentationProvider`](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring#config-options) to `springdoc`.  This will generate the spring java classes with appropriate springdoc annotations as well as the `swagger-ui.html` endpoint you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Including [Springdoc v2](https://springdoc.org/v2/) dependency into `pom.xml` generated a Swagger UI page based on the component-scanned controllers accessible at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html and its OpenAPI description at http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Note I use Spring Boot 3.0.2